# No obtiene los valores despues de la compra redsys

Tags: php

como dice el titulo, no obtiene los valores de la compra despues de haber realizado todo los pasos, y no entiendo, por qué, uso un archivo anteriormente desarrollado el cual funciona correctamente, pero en la web nueva no.

les dejo mis archivos a ver de repente me salte algo:

Redsys.php

```
<?PHP
include "apiRedsys.php";
$miObj              = new RedsysAPI;
$order              = date("ymdHis");
// Real

$url_tpvv           = 'https://sis.redsys.es/sis/realizarPago';
$clave              = 'xxxxxxxy';
$code               = 'xxxxxxx';
$terminal           = '1';

// Pruebas
/*
$url_tpvv           = 'https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago';
$clave              = 'xxxxx';
$code               = 'xxxxx';
$terminal           = '01';
*/
$version            = "HMAC_SHA256_V1";
$name               = 'EMPRESA X';
$amount             = $Total * 100;
$currency           = '978';
$consumerlng        = '001';
$transactionType    = '0';

if (isset($facturacionID)) {
    $urlMerchant        = $url_base_com . 'fpendiente.php';
    $urlweb_ok          = $url_base_com . 'pagofpendiente.php?ie=' . $Factura . '&amt=' . $precioTotal;
    $urlweb_ko          = $url_base_com . 'ptarjetap.php';
} else {
    $urlMerchant        = $url_base_com . 'formulario.php';
    $urlweb_ok          = $url_base_com . 'pago-tarjeta.php';
    $urlweb_ko          = $url_base_com . 'pago-cancelar.php';
}
// Importe
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT", $amount);
// Moneda
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY", $currency);
// Número de Pedido
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_ORDER", $order);
// Identificación de comercio: código FUC
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE", $code);
// Número de terminal
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL", $terminal);
// Tipo de transacción
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE", $transactionType);
// URL del comercio para la notificación online
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTURL", $urlMerchant);
// URL OK
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLOK", $urlweb_ok);
// URL KO
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLKO", $urlweb_ko);
// Identificación de comercio
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTNAME", $name);
// Idioma del titular
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_CONSUMERLANGUAGE", $consumerlng);
// Datos del comercio
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTDATA", $IDUnicoTarificador);
// Descripción del producto
// Ds_Merchant_ProductDescription
// Nombre y apellidos del titular
// Ds_Merchant_Titular
// Importe total (cuota recurrente)
// Ds_Merchant_SumTotal
$params    = $miObj->createMerchantParameters();
$signature = $miObj->createMerchantSignature($clave);

?>
```

pago-tarjeta.php

```
<?php
/* Iniciar sesion */
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", 10800);
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", 10800);
session_start();
/* Mostrar errores */
/*
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
*/
/* Datos de conexion a MS SQL Server */
include_once('inc/database.php');
/* Carga de cabecera y menu */
include_once('inc/header.php');
include_once('inc/sidebar.php');
include_once('inc/funciones.php');
?>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<?php
include "inc/apiRedsys.php";

$miObj           = new RedsysAPI;
$params          = $_GET['Ds_MerchantParameters'];
$decodec         = $miObj->decodeMerchantParameters($params);
$codigoRespuesta = $miObj->getParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT");
$obj             = json_decode($decodec);

$indice   = 0;
$aIdEnvio = array();

require 'vendor/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host        = 'localhost';
$mail->Username    = 'noreply@xxxxxxx.com';
$mail->Password    = 'xxxxxxx';
$mail->Port        = 25;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->setFrom('noreply@xxxxxxxxx.com', 'xxxxxxxx');

    /*************************************************
     * ACTUALIZAR DATOS GRABAR TRAS VOLVER PAGO RedSys
     * EXEC [dbo].[EnviosGrabarFormaDePago] 
     *************************************************/
    /* Conectar con el procedimiento almacenado */
    $stmt21       = mssql_init('EnviosGrabarFormaDePago');
    /* Parametros pasados al procedimiento almacenado */
    $ControlError = '';
    $EnvioID      = NULL;
    $FormaPago    = 36;
    $FechaPago    = date("Ymd");
    $MontoPago    = ($obj->Ds_Amount) / 100;
    mssql_bind($stmt21, '@ControlError', $ControlError, SQLVARCHAR, true, false, 40);
    mssql_bind($stmt21, '@EnvioID', $EnvioID, SQLINT1);
    mssql_bind($stmt21, '@IdentificadorEnvio', $obj->Ds_MerchantData, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 25);
    mssql_bind($stmt21, '@FormaDePago', $FormaPago, SQLINT1);
    mssql_bind($stmt21, '@FechaDePago', $FechaPago, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 19);
    mssql_bind($stmt21, '@ReferenciaPago', $obj->Ds_Order, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 40);
    mssql_bind($stmt21, '@MontoPago', $MontoPago, SQLFLT8);
    /* Ejecutamos el procedimiento */
    $resultado21 = mssql_execute($stmt21);
    $row         = mssql_fetch_row($resultado21);
    /* Liberar los recursos */
    mssql_free_statement($stmt21);

    /*****************************************************
     * OBTENER DATOS PARA ENVIO CORREO
     * EXEC [dbo].[EnviosSelectUnicoIdentificadorEnvioWEB]
     *****************************************************/
    /* Conectar con el procedimiento almacenado */
    $stmt27 = mssql_init('EnviosSelectUnicoIdentificadorEnvioWEB');
    /* Parametros pasados al procedimiento almacenado */
    mssql_bind($stmt27, '@ControlError', $ControlError, SQLVARCHAR, true, false, 40);
    mssql_bind($stmt27, '@IdentificadorEnvio', $obj->Ds_MerchantData, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 25);
    /* Ejecutamos el procedimiento */
    $resultado27 = mssql_execute($stmt27);
    $row27       = mssql_fetch_array($resultado27);
    /* Liberar los recursos */
    mssql_free_statement($stmt27);

    $aIdEnvio[0] = $row27['IdentificadorEnvio'];

 /* cuerpo del mensaje que se envia con los datos cuando se retornan */
 /* codigos extras del envio del correo */
?>
<p><strong>El pago se ha realizado correctamente:</strong></p>
<p>Importe: <?php echo $MontoPago; ?>€</p>
<p>Referencia: <?php echo $obj->Ds_Order; ?></p>
<p>Identificador envío: <?php echo $obj->Ds_MerchantData; ?></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a class="btnClose" href="<?php echo $url_base_com; ?>formulario.php" title="Volver">Volver</a></p>
```

La base de datos, esta OK, pero el problema es que no retornan los valores a la pagina "tarjeta-pago.php"

los valores del "apiRedsys.php" son estos:

```
<?php
/**
* NOTA SOBRE LA LICENCIA DE USO DEL SOFTWARE
* 
* El uso de este software está sujeto a las Condiciones de uso de software que
* se incluyen en el paquete en el documento "Aviso Legal.pdf". También puede
* obtener una copia en la siguiente url:
* http://www.redsys.es/wps/portal/redsys/publica/areadeserviciosweb/descargaDeDocumentacionYEjecutables
* 
* Redsys es titular de todos los derechos de propiedad intelectual e industrial
* del software.
* 
* Quedan expresamente prohibidas la reproducción, la distribución y la
* comunicación pública, incluida su modalidad de puesta a disposición con fines
* distintos a los descritos en las Condiciones de uso.
* 
* Redsys se reserva la posibilidad de ejercer las acciones legales que le
* correspondan para hacer valer sus derechos frente a cualquier infracción de
* los derechos de propiedad intelectual y/o industrial.
* 
* Redsys Servicios de Procesamiento, S.L., CIF B85955367
*/
class RedsysAPI{
    /******  Array de DatosEntrada ******/
    var $vars_pay = array();
    /******  Set parameter ******/
    function setParameter($key,$value){
        $this->vars_pay[$key]=$value;
    }
    /******  Get parameter ******/
    function getParameter($key){
        return $this->vars_pay[$key];
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////                    FUNCIONES AUXILIARES:                             ////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /******  3DES Function  ******/
    function encrypt_3DES($message, $key){
        // Se establece un IV por defecto
        $bytes = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0); //byte [] IV = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        $iv = implode(array_map("chr", $bytes)); //PHP 4 >= 4.0.2

        // Se cifra
        $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $message, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); //PHP 4 >= 4.0.2
        return $ciphertext;
    }
    /******  Base64 Functions  ******/
    function base64_url_encode($input){
        return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/', '-_');
    }
    function encodeBase64($data){
        $data = base64_encode($data);
        return $data;
    }
    function base64_url_decode($input){
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
    }
    function decodeBase64($data){
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        return $data;
    }
    /******  MAC Function ******/
    function mac256($ent,$key){
        $res = hash_hmac('sha256', $ent, $key, true);//(PHP 5 >= 5.1.2)
        return $res;
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////       FUNCIONES PARA LA GENERACIÓN DEL FORMULARIO DE PAGO:           ////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /******  Obtener Número de pedido ******/
    function getOrder(){
        $numPedido = "";
        if(empty($this->vars_pay['DS_MERCHANT_ORDER'])){
            $numPedido = $this->vars_pay['Ds_Merchant_Order'];
        } else {
            $numPedido = $this->vars_pay['DS_MERCHANT_ORDER'];
        }
        return $numPedido;
    }
    /******  Convertir Array en Objeto JSON ******/
    function arrayToJson(){
        $json = json_encode($this->vars_pay); //(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)
        return $json;
    }
    function createMerchantParameters(){
        // Se transforma el array de datos en un objeto Json
        $json = $this->arrayToJson();
        // Se codifican los datos Base64
        return $this->encodeBase64($json);
    }
    function createMerchantSignature($key){
        // Se decodifica la clave Base64
        $key = $this->decodeBase64($key);
        // Se genera el parámetro Ds_MerchantParameters
        $ent = $this->createMerchantParameters();
        // Se diversifica la clave con el Número de Pedido
        $key = $this->encrypt_3DES($this->getOrder(), $key);
        // MAC256 del parámetro Ds_MerchantParameters
        $res = $this->mac256($ent, $key);
        // Se codifican los datos Base64
        return $this->encodeBase64($res);
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////// FUNCIONES PARA LA RECEPCIÓN DE DATOS DE PAGO (Notif, URLOK y URLKO): ////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /******  Obtener Número de pedido ******/
    function getOrderNotif(){
        $numPedido = "";
        if(empty($this->vars_pay['Ds_Order'])){
            $numPedido = $this->vars_pay['DS_ORDER'];
        } else {
            $numPedido = $this->vars_pay['Ds_Order'];
        }
        return $numPedido;
    }
    function getOrderNotifSOAP($datos){
        $posPedidoIni = strrpos($datos, "<Ds_Order>");
        $tamPedidoIni = strlen("<Ds_Order>");
        $posPedidoFin = strrpos($datos, "</Ds_Order>");
        return substr($datos,$posPedidoIni + $tamPedidoIni,$posPedidoFin - ($posPedidoIni + $tamPedidoIni));
    }
    function getRequestNotifSOAP($datos){
        $posReqIni = strrpos($datos, "<Request");
        $posReqFin = strrpos($datos, "</Request>");
        $tamReqFin = strlen("</Request>");
        return substr($datos,$posReqIni,($posReqFin + $tamReqFin) - $posReqIni);
    }
    function getResponseNotifSOAP($datos){
        $posReqIni = strrpos($datos, "<Response");
        $posReqFin = strrpos($datos, "</Response>");
        $tamReqFin = strlen("</Response>");
        return substr($datos,$posReqIni,($posReqFin + $tamReqFin) - $posReqIni);
    }
    /******  Convertir String en Array ******/
    function stringToArray($datosDecod){
        $this->vars_pay = json_decode($datosDecod, true); //(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)
    }
    function decodeMerchantParameters($datos){
        // Se decodifican los datos Base64
        $decodec = $this->base64_url_decode($datos);
        return $decodec;    
    }
    function createMerchantSignatureNotif($key, $datos){
        // Se decodifica la clave Base64
        $key = $this->decodeBase64($key);
        // Se decodifican los datos Base64
        $decodec = $this->base64_url_decode($datos);
        // Los datos decodificados se pasan al array de datos
        $this->stringToArray($decodec);
        // Se diversifica la clave con el Número de Pedido
        $key = $this->encrypt_3DES($this->getOrderNotif(), $key);
        // MAC256 del parámetro Ds_Parameters que envía Redsys
        $res = $this->mac256($datos, $key);
        // Se codifican los datos Base64
        return $this->base64_url_encode($res);  
    }
    /******  Notificaciones SOAP ENTRADA ******/
    function createMerchantSignatureNotifSOAPRequest($key, $datos){
        // Se decodifica la clave Base64
        $key = $this->decodeBase64($key);
        // Se obtienen los datos del Request
        $datos = $this->getRequestNotifSOAP($datos);
        // Se diversifica la clave con el Número de Pedido
        $key = $this->encrypt_3DES($this->getOrderNotifSOAP($datos), $key);
        // MAC256 del parámetro Ds_Parameters que envía Redsys
        $res = $this->mac256($datos, $key);
        // Se codifican los datos Base64
        return $this->encodeBase64($res);   
    }
    /******  Notificaciones SOAP SALIDA ******/
    function createMerchantSignatureNotifSOAPResponse($key, $datos, $numPedido){
        // Se decodifica la clave Base64
        $key = $this->decodeBase64($key);
        // Se obtienen los datos del Request
        $datos = $this->getResponseNotifSOAP($datos);
        // Se diversifica la clave con el Número de Pedido
        $key = $this->encrypt_3DES($numPedido, $key);
        // MAC256 del parámetro Ds_Parameters que envía Redsys
        $res = $this->mac256($datos, $key);
        // Se codifican los datos Base64
        return $this->encodeBase64($res);   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: podría ser algo tonto pero, veo que no inicializas la clase así: `$miObj = new RedsysAPI();` ?

Comment: Lo dices solo porque no uso un espaciado ? No lo creo, si no, no hubiese funcionado en el otro, pero lo tomaré en cuenta para realizar de nuevo mi prueba.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no es clara. Dices que *no retorna los valores de `pago-tarjeta.php`*, pero resulta que ese archivo no retorna nada. El archivo usa elementos varios de tu sistema los cuales debes depurar todos: conexión a la base de datos, inclusión de la librería PHPMailer, inclusión de las clases que usas, etc. El código puede fallar por infinidad de motivos, como que la base de datos no existe en ese entorno, o que los archivos que incluyes no tienen las rutas correctas o que la librería PHPMailer no existe en el entorno, etc, etc, etc. Depurar o revisa el errorlog.

Comment: Lo solucione, el problema nunca fue el codigo, era solo habilitar una opcion dentro de "redsys La Caixa" que no estaba habilitado, problema solucionado.
Para algun otro que este trabajando con redsys y con esta empresa en si, debera de ir a "Datos de configuración" debe estar marcada la opcion de "Enviar parámetros en las URLs*" en SI para que se envien los datos y se muestren en el correo.

Saludos ! y muchas gracias.